# Discord.js command.name.toLowerCase() is not working

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm working on discord.js bot V13 and I came across this error

**Code:**

```
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const cooldowns = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name.toLowerCase(), command);//Errors at command.name.toLowerCase()
}
```

**Help With:**
I just want to convert The string (command.name.toLowerCase()) but it sends an error i have also tried in VScode but it sends error there also error is same
Error:

**TypeError:** Cannot read property ‘toLowerCase’ of undefined

Any information please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: the method is not the problem. name in itself is undefined, you are probably accessing the wrong value, or it just doesn't have a value.

Comment: one or more of your command files doesn't export a `name`

Answer (score 0):

Use `.toLowerCase()` in your event

Eg:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ')
    const cmd = args[0].toLowerCase()
    const command = client.commands.get(cmd)
    if(!command) return;
    try{
       await command.execute(message, args)
    } catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }

})
```

Comment: thanks, but I added it and it still didn't work

Comment: What isn't working/error?

Comment: still having the same error

Comment: Did you remove `.toLowerCase()` from the handler

Comment: Positive, Here is my event: module.exports = (client, message) => {
    if (message.author.bot || message.channel.type === 'dm') return;

    const prefix = client.config.discord.prefix;

    if (message.content.indexOf(prefix) !== 0) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const cmd = client.commands.get(command) || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(command));

    if (cmd) cmd.execute(client, message, args);


};